# is it possible to use multiple lines in a gitlab ldap filter?

Tags: ldap, gitlab

I would like to use multiple lines in the ldap filter in gitlab.  Can I do something like this:

```
'(|
    (&(objectClass=user)(memberOf=CN=group1,OU=User Groups,DC=local))
    (&(objectClass=user)(memberOf=CN=group1,OU=Security Groups,DC=local))
)'
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this question?  I am interested in your solution.

Comment: I didn't find an answer, and I didn't get it to work.  I suspect it was my lack of understanding of the ldap filter syntax and how the auth process uses it.  I got it working with the default and moved on.